# Merge SQL statement and Matched record casting

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

My query in SQL Server looks tries to merge only the records that have changed instead of updating every single one so I insert a simple AND statement after the MATCHED clause and it's working perfectly except for one thing. In C# I understand how you might have to cast variables to different types in order to compare them but I "assumed" in SQL that wasn't the case.  The source column is a numeric(19,5) and the destination is decimal(18,4).  For our purposes I'm not worried about the truncation of data,  eventually I will change the target so it's will hold more i.e. (20,6)

Here's the statement:

```
WHEN MATCHED 
AND (((ISNULL(source.WorkOrderItemNumber,'') != ISNULL(target.WorkOrderItemNumber,'')) 
OR (ISNULL(CAST(source.WorkOrderQty as DECIMAL(18,4)),0) != ISNULL(target.WorkOrderQty,0)

-- ISNULL(source.WorkOrderQty,0) != ISNULL(target.WorkOrderQty,0)

) 

OR (ISNULL(source.WorkOrderBatchQty,0) != ISNULL(target.WorkOrderBatchQty,0)

)))
```

When I run the above statement it does the correct thing and doesn't run the corresponding update statement. When I uncomment the second line and use it instead it doesn't work properly. It will say that the record is different and run the corresponding UPDATE statement.

The `WorkOrderBatchQty` works properly  but it's different in that I'm hardcoding `0.00000 AS WorkOrderBatchQty`, into the statement and the target destination is decimal (18,4)

I can see why it works but I don't understand why it doesn't work both ways?  I didn't think SQL used casting that way when comparing values.  I guess 14.00000 is different than 14.0000 but I didn't think SQL would care.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the MSDN type conversion chart, decimal and numeric conversion [(r)equires explicit CAST to prevent the loss of precision or scale that might occur in an implicit conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx).  Look for the big asterisks in the chart.

So you do need an inline type conversion like:

```
ISNULL(CAST(source.WorkOrderQty AS DECIMAL(18, 4)), 0) != ISNULL(target.WorkOrderQty, 0)
```

Comment: You know I think I scrolled right past that chart when I was looking for the answer.  I knew WHY it was asking for the CAST I just couldn't prove it.  Thanks!